# Accessing all odd indices of a 3D matrix then all even in a more efficient way

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, matrix, indexing

So i have a 3D numpy matrix, in which i want to access only the odd indices first and then once i have accessed all the odd ones i then want to access the even ones. At the moment to do this i have two triple nested for loops but this is really slow. What i have at the moment can be seen below. The first if statements is because i dont have to access the edge of the cube. Also im going to be doing something else to the Matrix[i,j,k] and making it just equal to a number but my problem is accessing the odds and then the evens efficiently.

```
        for i in range(self.size):
            for j in range(self.size):
                for k in range(self.size):
                    if i==0 or i==(self.size-1) or j==0 or j==(self.size-1) or k==0 or k==(self.size-1): 
                        pass
                    elif (i+j+k)% 2==1:
                         Matrix[i,j,k]=2

                    else:
                        pass

        for i in range(self.size):
            for j in range(self.size):
                for k in range(self.size):
                    if i==0 or i==(self.size-1) or j==0 or j==(self.size-1) or k==0 or k==(self.size-1): 
                        pass
                    elif (i+j+k)% 2==0:
                         Matrix[i,j,k]=4
                    else:
                        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the remainder of the sum, but it doesn't necessary gives you the odd or the even, because odd + odd + even will be even number. Nevertheless, you can use the fact, that NumPy support not only scalars as indices. And also you can omit using `if` with a `pass` if you specify `range(1, self.size-1)`. You can use the next code:

```py
Matrix[range(1,self.size-1,2),range(1,self.size-1,2),range(1,self.size-1,2)]=2
Matrix[range(2,self.size-1,2),range(2,self.size-1,2),range(2,self.size-1,2)]=2
```

Third parameter allows you to iterate on every second number

Comment: How would i then, access the matrix element through the iteration index, if that makes sense? I basically want to iterate through this matrix(A) and then at each element i want to change another matrix's(B) element that is at the same position as the element in matrix A.